# Session sharing between two application deployed on same Tomcat Server

Tags: angular, session, tomcat, session-cookies

I have many applications running and deployed on same Tomcat Server. All these application has a common UI using DOJO framework. Plan is to move from DOJO to Angular framework(Deploy Angular as another application on the same Tomcat server).

Since all changes related to UI cannot be done in one release, plan is to move page by page to Angular. If user click on some page in DOJO and if that page is already implemented in Angular, then we must open that page in a separate window. But the issue is how do i move session from DOJO application to Angular? Also if users logs out of UI with DOJO, session should be invalidated in Angular.

Is this plan possible? if yes how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I could use some more information. What is your current authentication strategy? If you are using SSO you can integrate it with angular no problem. As for the rest of the session data. Can you tell me how it is stored right now local storage/cookies? Or is stored in the backend?

Comment: @piotrszybicki Had to go through lot of code. Authentication can be SSO or from DB based on deployment. Currently in DOJO application, sessionID is stored in cookies.  I would actually need this session id to be validated in my Angular UI.